# System call to run pbmtextps: ghostscript

Tags: perl

I'm coding a Perl script to generate images with text in them.  I'm on a Linux machine.  I'm using `pbmtextps`.  When I try to run pbmtextps in Perl with a system call like this

```
system("pbmtextps -fontsize 24 SampleText > out.pbm");
```

I get this error message

```
pbmtextps: failed to run Ghostscript process: rc=-1
```

However, if I run the exact same pbmtextps command from the command-line outside of Perl, it runs with no errors.

Why does it cause the ghostscript error when I run it from inside a Perl script?

ADDITIONAL INFO: I tried to hack around this by creating a C code called mypbmtextps.c which does the exact same thing with a C system call.  That works from the command line.  No errors.  But then when I call that C program from the Perl script, I get the same ghostscript error.

ANSWER: I solved it.  The problem was this line in the PERL script:
    $SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE';
When I got rid of that (which I need for other things, but not in this script) it worked okay.  If anyone knows why that would cause a problem, please add that explanation.

Comment: Note that system runs the arguments it has in /bin/sh. When you run the 'pbmtextps' command externally which is the shell you are running it in (Is it a csh/tcsh) ?

Comment: I've run the command externally in /bin/sh, /bin/csh, and /bin/tcsh with no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah-ha.  Well, the SIGCHLD is required for wait(), and so required for perl to be able to retrieve the exit status of the child process created by system().  In particular, system() always returns -1 when SIGCHLD is ignored.  $? will also be unavailable with SIGCHLD blocked.

What printed the error message?  pbmtextps, or your perl script?

As far as I know, the signal handler for your perl process shouldn't affect the signal handler for the child processes, but this could depend on your version of perl and your OS version.  On my Linux Mint 13 with Perl 5.14.2 the inner perl script prints 0, with the outer script printing -1:

```
perl -e '$SIG{CHLD}= "IGNORE"; print system(q{perl -e "print system(q(/bin/sleep 1))"})'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your perl script modifying the environment?

You can test with

```
system("env > /tmp/env.perl");
```

and then compare it to the environment form your shell:

```
env > /tmp/env.shell
diff /tmp/env.shell /tmp/env.perl
```

Is the perl script also being run from the shell, or is it being run from some other process like cron or apache?  (in particular, you should check $PATH)

Comment: I did this and the only difference is that env.perl has SHLVL=2, while the other has SHLVL=1.  Also, env.perl has this line at the end: _=/usr/bin/env

Comment: Next thing to try is seeing if the STDIN / STDOUT are having some effect on it.  Try with

    sh -c "pbmtextps -fontsize 24 SampleText > out.pbm </dev/null 2>/dev/null"

Comment: See my ANSWER above in the original message.